# Excel 2007 bar chart auto axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am creating a bar chart with values ranging from 100 to 100,000. I keep the X axis as auto scaling allowing me to change the starting point.

From what I understand, if two bars variance is greater than 1/6 (16.6%) the graph will start from 0, and if the difference is less than 1/6 (16.6%) the graph will auto scale.

I want to auto scale irrespective of whether the variance is greater than 16.6% or not. How can I do this?

Comment: Apart that most of times it is not a good idea to not start the (X sure? maybe Y?) axis from zero, what do you expect? That is, what would auto scale have to do when the difference is greater than 1/6?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options with auto-scaling: on or off. If the behaviour of the auto-scaling doesn't meet your requirements, then you have to turn it off and find a way of scaling it appropriately yourself. You cannot alter the auto-scaling behaviour.

Other than manually setting the axes, the only other option is to create a macro which carries out the desired behaviour, based on scaling values you calculate yourself.

An example is given here: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AxisScaleLinkToSheet.html